# How to Solve Error Message ReferenceError: req is not defined in NodeJS application

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

i'm doing exercise where i'm using MERN , during my test in postman i have this message <<req is not defined>>  since i was looking for on the internet i did'nt find any good thing if someone can help i will go fast to finish my learning .
here is my server.js

```
import express from "express"
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import userRoute from "./routes/user.route.js"
import gigRoute from "./routes/gig.route.js"
import orderRoute from "./routes/order.route.js"
import conversationRoute from "./routes/conversation.route.js"
import messageRoute from "./routes/message.route.js"
import reviewRoute from "./routes/review.route.js"
import authRoute from "./routes/auth.route.js"
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"
import cors from "cors"

const app= express()

dotenv.config()
mongoose.set('strictQuery',true)

const connect = async () =>{    
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO);
        console.log("connected to mongo db")
    } catch (error) {
        // handleError(error);
        console.log(error)
    }
}
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5173", credentials: true }));
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use("/api/auth",authRoute)
app.use("/api/users",userRoute)
app.use("/api/gigs",gigRoute)
app.use("/api/orders",orderRoute)
app.use("/api/conversations",conversationRoute)
app.use("/api/messages",messageRoute)
app.use("/api/reviews",reviewRoute)

/**
 * gestion d'erreur 
 */
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    const errorStatus = err.status || 500
    const errorMessage = err.message || "Something went wrong!"

    return res.status(errorStatus).send(errorMessage)
})

app.listen(8800,()=>{
    connect()
    console.log("Backend server is running")
})
```

and my gigRoute is :

```
import express from "express";
import { verifyToken } from "../middleware/jwt.js";
import {
    createGig, 
    deleteGig,
    getGig,
    getGigs
} from "../controllers/gig.controller.js"

const router= express.Router()

router.post("/",verifyToken,createGig)
router.delete("/:id",verifyToken,deleteGig)
router.get("/single/:id",verifyToken,getGig)
router.get("/single/:id",verifyToken,getGigs)

export default router
```

and my gigController code

```
import Gig from "../models/gig.model.js"
import creatorError from "../utils/creatorError.js"


export const createGig = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.isSeller)
    return next(createError(403, "Only sellers can create a gig!"));

  const newGig = new Gig({
    userId: req.userId,
    ...req.body,
  });

  try {
    const savedGig = await newGig.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedGig);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

for the first time i was trying to run it on postman but  when i'm running this endpoint http://localhost:8800/api/gigs i still have the message i write above